# Style apex:inputText as required within apex:pageBlockSectionItem

Tags: visualforce, inputtext

I have a number of fields that I'm binding to within a pageBlockSection. In most cases I can use an inputField to get the standard Salesforce presentation.

However, one of the required fields I want to bind to isn't an SObject field. It is a property defined on an inner class of the controller.

**Basic Visualforce**

```
<apex:pageBlock id="dropBlock" mode="edit">
     <apex:pageBlockSection title="Elements" columns="1" showHeader="false">
         <!-- ... a number of other pageBlockSectionItems-->  
         <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
             <apex:outputLabel value="Required String Property" />
             <apex:inputText value="{!innerClassInstance.innerClassField}" required="true"/>
         </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
     </apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

Attempting to use an inputField for the default rendering results in the error message:

> Save error: Could not resolve the entity from  value
>   binding '{!innerClassInstance.innerClassField}'.   can only be used with
>   SObject fields.

If I take the inputText field out of the pageBlockSectionItem and pageBlockSection I can fake it by using a couple of divs and the Salesforce styles, but then it is no longer aligned with the other fields in the pageBlockSection.

```
<div class="requiredInput">
    <div class="requiredBlock"></div>
    <apex:inputText value="{!innerClassInstance.innerClassField}" required="true"/>
</div>
```

I can't put the extra divs in the pageBlockSectionItem as I get the error:

> Save error:  may have no more than 2 child components

**How can I add the default Salesforce required mark to an inputText within a pageBlockSectionItem?**

I did see the related question [Visualforce markup used to display a required password field, with field type “password”](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1142/visualforce-markup-used-to-display-a-required-password-field-with-field-type-p). The issue is very similar, and the like to the discussion boards is useful. This question differs slightly as I specifically want to work within a pageBlockSectionItem for presentation reasons.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While writing out the question I came up with one possible solution. Just enclose the inputField and the additional divs in an outputPanel.

Hopefully it helps someone else who has this requirement.

```
<apex:pageBlock id="dropBlock" mode="edit">
    <apex:pageBlockSection title="Elements" columns="1" showHeader="false">
        <!-- ... a number of other pageBlockSectionItems-->  
        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
            <apex:outputLabel value="Required String Property" />
            <apex:outputPanel layout="block" styleClass="requiredInput">
                    <div class="requiredBlock"></div>
                    <apex:inputText value="{!innerClassInstance.innerClassField}" required="true"/>
            </apex:outputPanel>
        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

Comment: Do you need to use divs? What if instead of having the extra outputPanel container you just changed your divs to apex:outputPanel layout="block"?  (I've used your extra containing outputPanel trick before when I had to put a table element inside of an pageBlockSectionItem...the error message is very misleading...)

Comment: @PeterKnolle. Good idea. Using `layout="block" styleClass="requiredInput"` on the outputPanel I can skip one of the divs.