# Apex validations removing parameters from url

Tags: visualforce, force.com-sites

I have a VF page which has a Save and cancel button and i am using this page on Sites.

The issue that i have is
Whenever there is a validation like a Required field is not entered then an apex:message is shown that value is required. But after that the parameters in the url is lost.

For example

If the url of the VF page is
http://abc-developer-edition.ap1.force.com/Candidate?jobId=a039000000jc8koAAA

after the validation error url changes to 
http://abc-developer-edition.ap1.force.com/Candidate

(It removes the parameters)

```
<apex:commandButton action="{!SaveResult}" value="Submit" styleclass="btn btn-primary"/>
```

SaveResult is a controller method where i save the record. Everything works fine when all the values are entered correct.

I am using the required in VF page this way.

```
<apex:inputField value="{!field_disp[f.fieldPath]}" required="{!OR(f.required, f.dbrequired)}"  styleClass="form-control"/>
```

Any thoughts what could be causing this?

Thanks

Comment: what does your SaveResult method returns?

Comment: It returns a page reference. Thats not the issue. It works fine with all values correctly fed in. The validation are on client side (i assume) because i have required="true" in apex:inputField

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't put a rerender in the commandbutton, it will rerender the entire page if `null` is returned from the `SaveResult` method. And it rerenders the page without the page parameters. I guess the same happens for the `required="true"` parameter.

When I had this problem I added `rerender="[some id of e.g. the form]"` to the commandbutton, which made it work fine because it will only rerender that part and leave the url as it is.

Comment: mmm.. interesting. I have a Apex:inputFile in my form which is resulting in an error  commandLink that specifies a rerender or oncomplete attribute.

Comment: apex:inputFile tag does not allow you to use any other tag specifying rerender attribute in the same form. Either you need use IFrame strategy something like this (https://github.com/Katulka/SalesforceIframeInputFile) or use the @RemoteAction way by reading the file contents using js and sending over to controller. Good Luck!

Comment: apex:inputfile... Bad news :-) As an alternative to javanoob's methods you could also consider replacing the 'required' tag with just the required markup and doing the validation (+ possibly an error) in your controller. See an example here: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/2108/style-apexinputtext-as-required-within-apexpageblocksectionitem

Answer (score 1):

Salesforce [strips all the parameters](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000229987&type=1) except for `id` (**lowercase only!**, `Id` or `ID` will also be removed) for the `action` attribute of the HTML `form` tag. Any command button will send a POST request to this address, so if no redirect is performed you will stay there.

The obvious suggestion is to only use `id` parameter and grab all other info from database (or serialize all your parameters into one *id* string in extreme cases).

Comment: This seems to be correct, all params get stripped except for id