# Required field mark (Red Vertical Bar) not coming

Tags: visualforce

I have created a input text field and  want to make this field required and I did it through required attribute. I also want to put red vertical bar in front of text field which is required indicator in salesforce.
I did follow code but red bar is not showing -

```
            <div class="requiredInput">
                <div class="requiredBlock"></div>
                <apex:inputText value="{!name}" label="Name on Card" required="true"/>
            </div>
```

How do I get the red bar to display?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Visualforce markup used to display a required password field, with field type "password"](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1142/visualforce-markup-used-to-display-a-required-password-field-with-field-type-p)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can "simulate" the redbar like this:

```
<apex:pageBlock >
    <apex:pageBlockSection>
        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
            <apex:outputPanel>
                <div class="requiredInput">
                    <div class="requiredBlock"></div>
                    <apex:inputText value="{!numberOfRowToRemove}"/>
                </div>
            </apex:outputPanel>
        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

Answer (score 5):

Finally i have find out the solution.

```
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                <apex:outputLabel value="Name on Card" />
                <apex:outputPanel >
                    <div class="requiredInput">
                        <div class="requiredBlock"></div>
                        <apex:inputText value="{!name}" label="Name on Card"                     
                        required="true"/>
                    </div>
                </apex:outputPanel>
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
```

above code must be wrapped under apex:pageBlockSectionItem tag.

Answer (score 3):

It is because you are using inputText.  The red bar doesn't come with inputText.  You might want to consider inputField to get the bar if the field is an sObject field.

See [Visualforce markup used to display a required password field, with field type "password"](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1142/visualforce-markup-used-to-display-a-required-password-field-with-field-type-p).

Answer (score 2):

For apex:inputField fields, you can add required="true"

Eg,

This will create a red bar against the field