# Required not working on picklist change

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am trying to make an input field required on the basis of selected picklist value , However, Its not working when I tried to submit the form. I have checked the value its rendering on change.

```
<apex:selectList multiselect="false" size="1" label="Record" styleClass="slds-select slds-size_1-of-2" value="{!FilterValue}" id="populate">
                <apex:selectOption itemValue="None" itemLabel="--None--"/>
                <apex:selectOption itemValue="Accountc" itemLabel="Account Name"/> <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="fieldBlock"/>
        </apex:selectList>
     <!-- </th>
      <th scope="col">
       <span class="slds-badge">Search Text</span> -->

       <apex:outputPanel id="fieldBlock">

          <apex:inputText label="Search Text"  value="{!Search}" styleclass="slds-input slds-size_1-of-3" html-placeholder="{!FilterValue}" id="search" required="{IF({!FilterValue}=='None',false,true)}"/>

      </apex:outputPanel>
```

Comment: You need to call an action, to send back your changes. If no action is called, the page just get's refreshed.

Answer (score 1):

So in your code I see multiple things to be modified.

Firstly, you are using `inputText`, wherein by design **the required attribute simply makes the field required for the Ajax request. The red mark would not appear by default.** Refer [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/140530/apexinputtext-with-required-true-using-apexpageblocktable) for more details.

If possible try using `inputField` instead.

Also the `IF condition` that you have written, seems syntactically incorrect to me.

Try using it this way:

```
required="{!IF(FilterValue=='None',false,true)}
```

Also, you need to wrap the select list inside a `<apex:actionRegion>`, as after first selection when the `inputText` becomes required. The field will not be rendered `onchange` of picklist unless `inputText` has some value(as it has become required now).

Add `<apex:pagemessages></apex:pagemessages`> in a VisualForce Page always, so you can read the errors on the Page. In this way, you can understand whether you are getting the required input error or not.

I myself, tried this and below is a working copy of the code:

**VisualforcePage**

```
<apex:page controller="TestFieldController">
<apex:pagemessages></apex:pagemessages>
<apex:form >
<apex:pageBlock>
    <apex:pageBlockSection>
    <apex:actionRegion>
        <apex:selectList multiselect="false" size="1" label="Record" styleClass="slds-select slds-size_1-of-2" value="{!filterValue}" id="populate">
            <apex:selectOption itemValue="None" itemLabel="--None--"/>
            <apex:selectOption itemValue="Accountc" itemLabel="Account Name"/> 
            <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="fieldBlock"/>
        </apex:selectList>
    </apex:actionRegion>
    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
        <apex:outputLabel value="Search Text" />
        <apex:outputPanel id="fieldBlock">
        <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!AND(filterValue!='None',!ISBLANK(filterValue))}">
        <div class="requiredInput"> <div class="requiredBlock"></div>
          <apex:inputText label="Search Text"  value="{!Search}" styleclass="slds-input slds-size_1-of-3" html-placeholder="{!filterValue}" id="searchRequired" required="true"/>
        </div>
        </apex:outputPanel>
        <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!OR(filterValue=='None',ISBLANK(filterValue))}">
          <apex:inputText label="Search Text"  value="{!Search}" styleclass="slds-input slds-size_1-of-3" html-placeholder="{!filterValue}" id="searchNotRequired" required="false"/>
        </apex:outputPanel>
      </apex:outputPanel>
    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock>
<apex:commandButton value = "Submit" action="{!callController}"/>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**Controller:**

```
public class TestFieldController{

  public String filterValue{get;set;}
  public String Search{get;set;}

  public void callController(){
  }
}
```

> Here I have used two different inputText controls and rendered them
>   accordingly as per the requirement, just to display the red bar
>   besides the field
>
> If you use `inputField` instead of `inputText`, you can handle this by
>   single control.

I have added a button too, to verify whether the field gives error on submit. Let me know if you are still facing any issue.