# Trying to add Required mark without using required = true for input fields with pageblocksection inside outputpanel

Tags: visualforce-component

```
         <apex:outputpanel styleClass="requiredInput" d="Account_Info_section" layout="block">
               <apex:pageblockSection title="Account Info (All Fields are Required)" rendered="{!NOT(existingAccount)}" collapsible="no" columns="2" >



        <!-- Market -->

        <apex:inputField value="{!leadConvert.Market__c}" id="marketField"> 
            <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="AdDelivery_Info,ContentProvider_Info,WWS_Info,MVPD_Info"/>
        </apex:inputField>

        <!-- Company Type -->

        <apex:inputfield value="{!leadConvert.Company_Type__c}"  >
                 <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="AdDelivery_Info"/>
               </apex:inputField>

        <apex:inputField value="{!leadConvert.Region__c}" id="region"/>   
        <apex:inputField value="{!leadConvert.Street}" id="street"/>
        <apex:inputField styleClass="requiredInput" value="{!leadConvert.City}" id="city"/>       
        <apex:inputField value="{!leadConvert.State}" id="state"/> 
        <apex:inputField value="{!leadConvert.Country}" id="Country"/>
        <apex:inputField value="{!leadConvert.PostalCode}" id="PostalCode"/>







         </apex:pageblockSection> 
         </apex:outputpanel>
```

Comment: If I try to bring output panel inside pageblocksection and use layout = block with div style class requiredBlock and requiredInput alignment of fields is uneven.

Comment: @Prudvi, not sure if I understand your issue, you could also use a Javascript to enforce the mandate and display an error if a required field does not have a value filled in. You could also, use a validation rule to enforce a mandate for each of the fields in consideration, only that writing the validation rule for each field it would be an overhead.

Comment: Hi Jigar,

We want to just use a red flag or highlighter on the fields and not enforce validation or JS for error display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The red highlighter for fields in Visualforce only displays when a field being used on the Visualforce page is marked as required in either of the following ways.

> 1. When the `required` attribute on the respective Visualforce component is set as `required = true`.
> 2. When an `<apex:inputField>` is being used and the corresponding field on the object, is marked as `Required`.

Other than this, if you intend to show the red highlighter, you will need to either use a custom stylesheets or identify the standard Salesforce style class being applied through the browser's ***Inspect Element*** feature and then apply the same `styleClass` on your respective component. I would recommend using the custom styling approach since, Salesforce could change the style classes at their end without notice in future causing the styling on your page to break.

Also, if alignment is an issue, you can use `<apex:pageBlockSectionItem>` within a `<apex:pageBlockSection>` for every individual field to have it display appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

Some blog posts to help:

1. JavaScript to ensure that the fields are filled: https://www.mkpartners.com/article/support/fieldvalidation
2. The markup in this question: [Required field mark (Red Vertical Bar) not coming](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/5462/required-field-mark-red-vertical-bar-not-coming)

That seems to be what you're looking for, if I'm reading you correctly.

And to echo another answer here: Putting every field inside a apex:pageBlockSectionItem tag is a best-practice when altering fields on a layout and not using apex:inputField by itself.